# Matrix Derivation for Neural Network Formula

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, matrix-calculus

I am learning some insights of Neural network but I have some problem with the derivation of matrix for backpropagation. On an assumption that the formula for calculating for one node in a neural network, which as been vectorized, is $Z^{[i]} = W^{[i]}A^{[i - 1]} + B^{[i]}$.

For notation,

$Z^{[i]}$ is the score for layer $i$,

$W^{[i]}$ is the weight coefficient for layer $i$,

$A^{[i - 1]}$ is the score for layer $i - 1$

$B^{[i]}$ is the bias coefficient for layer $i$

For backpropagation, we need to calculate for $dZ$, $dW$, $dA$, $dB$, toward a cost function L = f(Z), a function of Z.
In the other word, we need to calculate $dL/dZ$, $dL/dW$, $dL/dA$, $dL/dB$ respectively

For calculating $dZ$, $dB$, it has no problem. But for computing $dW$, $dA$, due to applying chain rule, it creates some confusions. For more details, the solution is stated as

$dW = \frac{dL}{dW} = \frac{dL}{dZ} \frac{dZ}{dW} = dZ A^{[i - 1]T}$

$dA = \frac{dL}{dA} = \frac{dL}{dZ} \frac{dZ}{dA} = W^{[i]T}dZ$

The confusion is that, I do not understand why in computing $dW$, $\frac{dZ}{dW}$ is  $A^{[i - 1]T}$. Moreover, in matrix multiplication property, it states that the multiplication of two matrices are not commutative or AB $\neq$ BA. Hence, why, in computing $dA$, $dZ$, which is derived from $\frac{dL}{dZ}$, could be standing behind $W^{[i]T}$?

I really hope that someone could help me to explain these two problems

Comment: What are the dimensions of these matrices, and do you have a link for the calculations' source?

Comment: Magnus "Differential Calculus" [book](https://www.sci-hub.se/10.1002/9781119541219) gives background on these kind of computations. $dL/dW$ is not standard notation when $W$ is a matrix. Normally you express matrix products as sums and do scalar differentiation, and then turn it back into matrices which gives results like $dW=dZ A^T$ which you just have to memorize. This [paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/NA-08-01.pdf) gives more such formulas

Answer (score 2):

The reason for getting a transpose after differentiation is how you define the derivative by a vector or a matrix. Let us take the simpler case of vectors. You can define the derivative $\frac{\partial \mathbf y}{\partial \mathbf x}$ either as

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf y}{\partial \mathbf x} = \left( \begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_N} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial y_M}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial y_M}{\partial x_N}
\end{array} \right)
$$

or

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf y}{\partial \mathbf x} = \left( \begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial y_M}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_N} \dots \frac{\partial y_M}{\partial x_N}
\end{array} \right)
$$

This is easy to see when we take the case of the scalar product $\alpha = \mathbf w^T \mathbf x = \sum_i w_i x_i$. Depending on the definition, you get either $\mathbf w$ or $\mathbf w^T$. This is very confusing since there is no wide consensus, and it is usually not discussed that there are two ways to perform these derivatives.

As you point out, matrix multiplication is, in general, not commutative. The order of the matrices, for example $d\mathbf Z \mathbf A^{[i-1]}$, is exactly the order in which they are multiplied. It is the derivative of the product. I think what is confusing is the transpose. But, as discussed above, is a consequence of the choice on the definition of derivative.

To get a grip on these derivatives it helped me to work them out from bottom to top. I.e. start with the scalar product, then the quadratic form $\mathbf{y^T Ax}$. Deriving with respect to $\mathbf x$ is the same as the scalar product case, $\mathbf w = \mathbf {y^TA}$. You can regard matrices as vectors of row or columns vectors.